# Android SSLEngine resume ssl session

Tags: java, android, tls1.2, sslengine, sslcontext

I’m using SSLEngine to encrypt data in Android,
The first Handshake is Ok and I have my encrypted Data, and I have my session id.

I want to resume my previous session to avoid creating a new session but in SSLEngine we don’t have the possibility to configure the sessionId to be setted in the ClientHello.

Anyone have an information how to resume session using SSLEngine in Android?